# Is there a way to use Geogebra Figures in my own Android Studio App

Tags: android, android-studio, geogebra

I'm programming a maths learning App in Android Studio for my students. I want to integrate some (interactive) Geogebra figures, so they can explore how functions change with different parameters.

Does anyone know how to integrate these figures in my App. What needs to be done in the .xml file and the activity to make this work.

I' gratefull for every Ideas
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

Here is a minmum working example:

Create a new Android Studio Projekt. Create a new file in the assets folder of the Projekt and name the file sample.html.
Open Geogebra and make a Figure, worksheet or whatever you like. If you're done save the file and share it with Geogebra. Press Ctrl+Shift+M. The html code is now in your clip board. Paste it in your created sample.html file in your assets folder.

Your xml-file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is your MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.geogebratest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    public String url1, url2,url3, url4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");


        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(false);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for me.
Cheers